# JSwing - Undecorated window not transparent despite being defined as transparent

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, transparent

I am trying to make [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LCwT.png) appear on my screen, with the background being transparent, as a simple test for a bigger program (being a virtual pet)

I am using the following code to do this:

```
// Java Program to implement the shaped window
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
class solve extends JFrame {

    // main class
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // try block
        try {

            // create a window
            JWindow w = new JWindow();

            // set a transparent  background of the window
            w.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

            // read the image
            BufferedImage i = ImageIO.read(new File("froge.png"));

            // create a panel
            JPanel p = new JPanel() {

                // paint the panel
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
                {
                    // extract the pixel of the image
                    for (int ii = 1; ii < i.getHeight(); ii++)
                        for (int j = 1; j < i.getWidth(); j++) {
                            // get the color of pixel
                            Color ty = new Color(i.getRGB(j, ii));

                            // if the color is more than 78 % white ignore it keep it transparent
                            if (ty.getRed() > 200 && ty.getGreen() > 200 && ty.getBlue() > 200)
                                g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                                // else set  the color
                            else
                                g.setColor(new Color(i.getRGB(j, ii)));

                            // draw a pixel using a line.
                            g.drawLine(j, ii, j, ii);
                        }
                }
            };

            // add panel
            w.add(p);

            // set the location
            w.setLocation(350, 300);

            // set the size of the window
            w.setSize(1120, 320);

            // set the visibility of the window
            w.setVisible(true);
        }
        // catch any exception
        catch (Exception e) {

            // show the error
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This code is pretty much copied and pasted from a geeks for geeks article that claims to achieve the same thing as what I am trying. To me, the code checks out but when I run it I am faced with a [black background on my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1aw3.jpg)

Comment: Just did, and on the background pixels, r g b are all all 0. When I flip around the comparison operators on that statement the background is indeed transparent, but also takes away a majority of the image.

Comment: Yep, that works nicely thank you. Although surely there is a way for it to make the pixels transparent based on the alpha value of each pixel instead of by looking for a specific colour?

Comment: Well that fixes it completely! thank you so much.

Comment: but why not just `g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);` ??

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Your panel should not be opaque (the default), so `p.setOpaque(false);`
- Your window should be a JFrame undecorated, so `JFrame w = new JFrame();` and `w.setUndecorated(true);`
- Since it's undecorated, you need a way to exit the application. I would suggest a key listener on the Escape key.
- If it still doesn't work also call `setOpaque(false)` on the `JFrame#getContentPane()` and `JFrame#getRootPane()`

There may be different behaviour depending on the OS. My experience shows that Linux doesn't like animation on transparent windows and there was a recent bug fix for Mac OS that I don't know if it's released yet.